# how to retrieve column value from result set

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, jdbc-odbc

when i run this  program i got this in the output screen.I don't know what is the problem is there any thing i am missing.

```
import org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
public class Operations 
{
        public static void main(String[] args){ 
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/temp");
           //String  name = "name";
            String qry = "select name FROM tempcql where key = detail";
            Statement smt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = smt.executeQuery(qry);
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("name"));
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(" : "+e.getMessage());
        }
            }
}
```

here is the output of this : java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=86 lim=91 cap=159]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try getting the bytes and converting that to a String:

```java
String name_result = new String(resultSet.getBytes("name"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(name_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes in your SQL string:

```
String qry = "select name FROM tempcql where key = 'detail'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value in the binary format.But you specified column type as string.Instead you need to say as follows:

```
ObjectInputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("name");
ByetBuffer bb = (ByteBuffer)is.readObject();
```